# Why does no current flow in a smartphone charger when it's plugged into a socket, but no phone is connected?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, voltage

According to the fact that a phone charger consists of a transfomer and a recitifier, there should - still - be a difference in potentials, even though no phone is attached to the charger.

Comment: Given that there are losses in the ac-dc conversion, a little current will still flow. But, with no path for current on the dc side to flow, a back emf is built up that opposes current.

Comment: What is the cause of this EMF? Is it - maybe - electromagnetic induction on the primary coil?

Comment: The most obvious thing to point to is the filtering capacitors on the dc side. They charge up, the diodes don't conduct anymore, so there is no way for current to flow...

Comment: Modern chargers are "switching power supplies", not transfomer and a recitifier. You can tell by the lighter weight. You could try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: These have a high frequency oscillator followed by a transformer (which can be much smaller due to the high frequency) and rectifier. I guess they have a control circuit that turns them off when there is no load.

Comment: Keep your laptop charger plugged in without the laptop having connected. After a while, you will notice that the adapter is slightly hotter than it was before. When you connect the laptop to the charger, you will see a larger increase in temperature. To summarize, there is current in the primary coil. The adapter is not simply a combination of a transformer and a rectifier, there are more components (voltage step down, rectification, filtering, regulation, etc).

Comment: A modern phone charger doesn't just consist of a transformer and a rectifier.

Answer (score -1):

Because the circuit is not complete. Think of it as a potential difference, but the resistance connecting them is infinite, ie, air. When phone is connected, circuit is complete and current flows. If you touch the charger tip with your tongue, you will feel slight tingling taste of electricty, as the circuit would still be complete.

Comment: The primary coil of the transformer is still a closed circuit.

Comment: To be honest, even the secondary coil is a closed circuit.

Comment: That part has some little losses. It dissipates as heat.